# Can I hide the activity class name in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Is there some way to hide the activity class name, like "xxx" below in AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<activity android:name="xxx" .. />
```

Or config it in another file?

ps: for one curious, I want it hide from a third party auto scan tool. Not like google play, some android markets (in China) have annoying restrictive competition practice, such as prohibit the use of admob sdk but use the one their provided. I don't wanna change my program for every market.

Comment: why you need to hide it?

Comment: you can name it something else.. which is not close to the actual..

Comment: @userSeven7s But I'm using the jar from sdk, you mean changing the jar package structure?

Comment: you cannot hide it then.. the name has to appear somewhere to indicate to the compiler of the its presence.

Answer (score 3):

I think you cannot hide the real name of an activity class. The name has to appear somewhere to indicate to the compiler of its presence. Otherwise the system will throw an exception `ActivityNotFoundException`

There is an option (`<activity-alias>`) to specify an alias for an activity,  but here too as expected the real name has to be given to allow mapping.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hide or rename your activity in the manifest file.
Because whenever your APK is installed, it looks for the information of all the activities, services and other resources from the manifest file.

So,if you specify a different name for the activity, it will give **Null Pointer Exception** and the application will force close.

You better look for some tricks on how to hide manifest content for ceratin tools or the one which you are talking about.

Comment: Actually, you'll get an `ActivityNotFoundException`, not a `NullPointerException`.